# JQuery hover issue with window resize

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
var winWidth = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
    winWidth = $(window).width();
    $(".home").hover(
        function () {
            $(".arrow-down").show();
            if (winWidth < 900) {
                $(".arrow-down").css("left", "70px");  
            }
            else {   
                $(".arrow-down").css("left", "100px");
            }
        },
        function () {
             $(".arrow-down").hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Basically, a `arrow-down` div is shown whenever a mouse hovers over the object `.home`. But I also want to move the `arrow-down` object over depending on what the size of the window is. The code works fine, there's only one small problem that occurs and I cannot figure out the reason. If I refresh the screen, the `arrow-down` div does not show when the mouse hovers over the object `.home`, but if I resize the screen, then the function works perfectly.

I'm guessing that the function is only called when the screen is resized, but I don't want that, I want the function to be called before the screen is resized.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Why not just move the hover event outside of the resize event?

Comment: Also set var winWidth = $(window).width()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, your function is only called on resize - refreshing or loading the page won't trigger it. To have your function triggered on both, change:

```
$(window).resize(function() { /* your code here */ });
```

to:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() { /* your code here */ });
```

[See jQuery $.on for more info.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is surrounded by the jquery call `$(window).resize` this function will only be called when the window is resized. Try moving the `$(".home").hover` call outside the `$(window).resize` call and only update the variable winWidth when the window is resized.

something like:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    winWidth = $(window).width();
});

$(".home").hover(
    function () {
        $(".arrow-down").show();
        if (winWidth < 900) {
            $(".arrow-down").css("left", "70px");  
        }
        else {   
            $(".arrow-down").css("left", "100px");
        }
    },
    function () {
        $(".arrow-down").hide();
    }
);
```

or like Damion Yeatman said you don't even have to declare the variable winWidth, You just need to use the `$(window).width();` function anytime you need to get the window width.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to check when the window is resized as you are running a function on hover.

```
$(".home").hover(
    function () {
        $(".arrow-down").show();
        if ($(window).width() < 900) {
            $(".arrow-down").css("left", "70px");  
        }
        else {   
            $(".arrow-down").css("left", "100px");
        }
    },
    function () {
         $(".arrow-down").hide();
    }
);
```

Hope this helps.